# SQL - Combine results in whileloop

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

i would like to get a single results using this code

```
DECLARE
@count INT = 1,
@cutoff DATETIME = '12/31/2015'

while @count < 30
  begin
   select COUNT(Accnumber) from table
    where DATEDIFF(day,TranDateTime,@cutoff) <= 0
  SET @count = @count + 1
end
```

---

EDIT: i already fix it. what i did was i add a variable for the table and insert into it and display the result. sorry for bad english :D

so,

```
 DECLARE
    @count INT = 1,
    @cutoff DATETIME = '12/31/2015',
    *@tbl table(result int)*

    while @count < 30
      begin
     *insert into @tbl*
       select COUNT(Accnumber) from table
        where DATEDIFF(day,TranDateTime,@cutoff) <= 0
      SET @count = @count + 1
    end

*select * from @tbl*
```

im new here i don't know how to format answers correctly. again thanks for the response.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: What is @janthisyear. Your question is unclear

Comment: Could you post expected result ,actual result

Comment: its okay now, i already fix it. thanks for the feedback guys!

Comment: Either post the solution and mark it as an answer or remove this question